# angualrjs directive on mutiple div tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am very new to AngularJs, I have created a directive for moving up and down in an ng-repeat lists. But I have 2 lists on the same page, and I am troubling in using same directive for both lists. Whenever a keypress happens it selects rows from both lists.

Below are the 2 div tags with custom directive 'arrowSelector'

```
<div id="_divlookup" class="row"
     style="background-color:#ffffff; overflow-X:hidden; overflow-y:auto; padding:0px; padding-left:10px;"
     arrow-selector  row-index="selectedRow" max-limit="list.length"
     call-function="selectItem(selectedRow,position)" 
     call-on="keypress">list items here</div>  

<div class="col-sm-12"  style="height:410px; overflow-y:scroll;"
     arrow-selector row-index="selectedRowIndex" max-limit="MainList.length"
     call-function="viewItem(selectedRowIndex,MainList[selectedRowIndex].ID)"
     call-on="keydown">second list items</div>
```

Below is the custom directive

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('mainApp')
        .directive('arrowSelector', arrowSelector);

    testDirective.$inject = ['$document', 'mainService'];

    function arrowSelector($document, mainService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                rowIndex: '=',
                maxLimit: '=',
                callOn: '@',
                callfunc: '&callFunction',
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

                $document.bind('keydown', function(e) {

                    var scrollTop = elem[0].scrollTop,
                        scrollHeight = elem[0].scrollHeight,
                        offsetHeight = elem[0].offsetHeight,
                        offsetTop = elem[0].offsetTop;

                    if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 37) {
                        if (scope.rowIndex == 0) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (scope.rowIndex > 0 && scope.rowIndex % 13 == 0) {
                            elem[0].scrollTop -= offsetHeight + 20;
                        }
                        scope.rowIndex--;
                        scope.$apply();
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if (scope.callOn == 'keydown') {
                            scope.callfunc();
                        }


                    }
                    if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 39) {
                        if (scope.rowIndex == scope.maxLimit - 1) {
                            return;
                        }

                        if (scope.rowIndex > 0 && scope.rowIndex % 13 == 0) {
                            elem[0].scrollTop += offsetHeight - 20;
                        }

                        scope.rowIndex++;
                        scope.$apply();
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if (scope.callOn == 'keydown') {
                            scope.callfunc();
                        }


                    }
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        scope.callfunc();

                    }

                });

            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: The issue is that both lists will listen to the keydown event. You should add some mechanism so that the directive will know whether or not it is concerned by the keydown event. How is your page supposed to work? A click on the list and then you expect the directive to do its job on that list?

Comment: is there any way I can bind this custom directive conditionally?

Comment: can you make it a minimal fiddle reproducing this?